# customize opencms carousel element

Tags: content-management-system, opencms

opencms provides carousel element. but as per my requirement i need a carousel with thumbnail(which is not available in opencms). do i need to make changes in carousel.jsp(in com.alkacon.bootstrap.formatters/formatters). if it is the right way then provide some documentation regarding customization of carousel element.

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
 <c:forEach var="item" items="${content.valueList.Item}" varStatus="status">
<div class="item<c:if test="${status.first}"> active</c:if>">
 <cms:img alt="" src="${item.value.Image}" scaleType="2" scaleColor="transparent" scaleQuality="75" noDim="true" cssclass="img-responsive"/>
<div class="carousel-caption">
<c:if test="${item.value.Headline.isSet}">
 <h3 ${item.rdfa.Headline}>${item.value.Headline}</h3>
</c:if>
 <p ${item.rdfa.text}>${item.value.Text}</p>
</div>
 </div>
 </c:forEach>
 </div>
```

Comment: i had solved by editing carousel jsp in formatters folder